# how to get the test case name in selenium web driver in ruby?

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am newbie to Selenium and I have this doubt. Say I have a code like this

```
it "test_name" do 
   #test code enter code here 
end
```

Is there any way I can get the "test_name" or is it possible to store that in a string and use it over there before it. Thanks ind advance

Comment: Can you bit specific to your need,so that I can help you out.

Comment: I want to print out the "test_name" while running my test cases

Answer (score 0):

While running your tests, pass a command line argument `-v`.
The V stands for `verbose`.

So for example

```
ruby test.rb -v
```